flask_socketio не работают на pythonanywhere
Суть в том, что у меня, в Пайчарме, работает всё как надо, а в pythonanywhere - не работает.
После отправки сообщения пользователем А пользователю Б, у пользователя Б должна обновиться страница. Для этого я использую flask_socketio.
Примерно так выглядит мой код:
app = Flask(__name__)
app.config['SECRET_KEY'] = 'secret!'
serializer = URLSafeTimedSerializer(app.config['SECRET_KEY'])
socketio = SocketIO(app, async_mode=async_mode)
thread = None
thread_lock = Lock()
login_manager = LoginManager()
login_manager.init_app(app)

@socketio.on('run_new_message')
def message(data):
    ***
    emit('my_response', {'user_name': user, 'message': message, 'user_id': id_user]},
         to=data[id_room])

А так, примерно, шаблон:
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"
        integrity="sha512-bLT0Qm9VnAYZDflyKcBaQ2gg0hSYNQrJ8RilYldYQ1FxQYoCLtUjuuRuZo+fjqhx/qtq/1itJ0C2ejDxltZVFg=="
        crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/socket.io/3.0.4/socket.io.js"
        integrity="sha512-aMGMvNYu8Ue4G+fHa359jcPb1u+ytAF+P2SCb+PxrjCdO3n3ZTxJ30zuH39rimUggmTwmh2u7wvQsDTHESnmfQ=="
        crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        var socket = io()
        
        socket.on('my_response', function (msg, cb) {
            $('#log').append('<div class="message"><b><a style="color: black" href="user/' + msg.user_id + '">' + msg.user_name + '</b></a><br><a style="word-wrap:break-word">' + msg.message + '</a></div>').html();
            let scroleSms = document.querySelector(".scrole_sms");
            scroleSms.scrollTop = scroleSms.scrollHeight;
            document.querySelector(".message-input").focus()
            if (cb)
                cb();
        });
        
        $('form#post_message').submit(function (event) {
            socket.emit('run_new_message', {'message': $('#new_message').val()})
            return false
        })
    )



<div id="log"></div>


<form action="#" method="POST" id="post_message" class="sms_login_form center_label">
    <input type="text" name="new_message" id="new_message">
</form>

Дело не в том, что какая-то ошибка в коде, а в том, что на pythonanywhere ничего не работает. В логе ошибок нет. Вместо этого сокеты не работают. Есть ли способ как-то починить?
